# Editing my profile pulls an older version

Tags: bug

I've just signed up a few minutes ago. Why I try to edit my site profile, it shows an old version:

[image]

The [same bug exists on SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/bug-editing-my-bio-pulls-up-some-old-version), and [kevin there](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin) was looking for another network site that exhibited the problem.

Comment: I've noticed this as well, though I don't recall on which site; it looks like [it's been reported already on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254266/254929), but without action since April.